# Padarray function translating

Tags: matlab, opencv, pad

I have to translate from Matlab to C this function:

```
 impadded = padarray(impadded, padSzVec, 'replicate', 'both');
```

Really it pads the array copying the last elements of the object impadded of every row and column(obtening a bigger object).

What I did is: (img is the original image)

```
Mat padded;
padded.create(img.rows + padSize, img.cols + padSize,img.type());
padded.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));
padded(Rect(padSize,padSize,img.rows,img.cols);
img.copyTo(padded);
```

I suppose I m padding but inserting 0 to have a bigger object. Someone cal help me to improve the code.

Comment: You can use `copyMakeBorder()` function in OpenCV to pad elements in whatever directions you like and it supports several types of padding. See doc : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=makeborder#copymakeborder

Comment: so I write what I did :                                                                Mat padded(img.rows +padSize*2,img.cols +padSize*2,img.depth());     copyMakeBorder(img,padded,padSize,padSize,padSize,padSize,BORDER_CONSTANT);

Comment: Is it righ? I will give you a vote. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think you want `BORDER_REPLICATE` instead. @AbidRahmanK: you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Amro : As you say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Since it solves the problem of OP, I am making my comment an answer)*

You can use **`copyMakeBorder()`** function in OpenCV to pad elements in whatever directions you like and it supports several types of padding. See the docs : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=makeborder#copymakeborder

`BORDER_CONSTANT` will add a constant value.

`BORDER_REPLICATE` will copy the border elements as such, and I think that is what you need in your problem.